# Storing object specific information in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a RPG game in Unity and I have a lot of different monsters (about 20, but will be expanded in the future). Current I use a controller for the battle scene where I load the enemy prefab by ID (For example /monster/1 or /monster/2), but there is more information I want to store about my monsters. They will have stats (defence, attack), drop item ID, HP and CB level. What is the best way to store this information so I can get it when I have the ID?

I'm from a Javascript background, where I would use a JSON file to store this information and look up from there. Is there an equivalent way of working in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend having a look at [ScriptableObjects](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects). I've been working with Unity for a few years now and find it to be the solution (for me).

Here is an example:

using UnityEngine;

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Units/Monster")]
public class Monster : ScriptableObject
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;    

    [TextArea(2, 5)]
    [SerializeField]
    protected string BaseDescription;

    public Sprite UiButtonSprite;
    public float Attack;

    public float Health;

    public int Armor;
    // etc.
 }
```

You can then go to your Assets window in Unity, create a new Monster object and fill in the information!

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a build-in solution for this: "ScriptableObject".

See [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects) and [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html) for examples.